# Unfortunately error in emulator when declare a button

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-emulator

When i declare a button in MainActivity.java , i get Unfortunately error in emulator

But when i comment the button declaration , no errors

This is MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.MalekAlrwily.multiplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
}



}
```

And this is main.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main2" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@android:string/ok"
    android:src="@drawable/sun" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help

Thanks in advance .

Comment: final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ; If you check the logcat the possible exception would be ClassCastException. Since you are trying to type cast the ImageButton to Button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because, you declare in `xml` as `ImageButton` and dynamically, you declare `Button`.

It should be:

```
final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

That is an `ImageButton` in your layout so you should use an `ImageButton` in your activity too.

```
final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
```

this should be

```
final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Iths Because u try load `ImageButton` as `Button`

You should use

```
final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have declare `Button` instead of `ImageButton` in java file.

declare it like this:

```
final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_start) ;
```